# Create Log of User Input from Batch code

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows Batch script I cobbled together from Google searches.  My latest attempts to find what I need have been a mixed bag.  I hope someone could assist.

Recently one of my users swears that my script opens and closes for them without their input.  I personally find this unlikely as any attempts to witness the "error" is impossible, and for years this script has worked flawlessly for our needs.

I'd like to add code to create an output.log of any user input while the batch is running.  I expect output to contain either y, n, or empty/nul if the user pressed ENTER on an empty prompt.

I can only use batch script due to business security restraints, so if this isn't possible then I'll have to figure some other way.

Would someone review and show me how to add the necessary code to achieve, if possible, what I need?

Thank you.

```
@echo off

SET /P ANSWER=Have checks been deposited and daily balance file saved (Y/N)?
echo You chose: %ANSWER%
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :yes)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes)

goto :no

:yes
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "DailyBalance.xlsm" %%e-%%f-%%g-Deposit.xlsm
echo File Rename Complete!
pause
move "C:\Deposit\*Deposit.xlsm" "C:\Deposit\Complete\" 
echo Renamed File Move Complete!
pause
copy "C:\Deposit\Reset\DailyBalance.xlsm" "C:\Deposit\" 
echo Daily Balance File Refreshed and ready for tomorrow!
echo Daily Backup has completed!
pause
exit /b 0

:no
echo Please run DailyBackup once the deposit has been completed.
pause
exit /b 1
```

Comment: I suggest you change to using the `CHOICE` command for YES/NO input questions.  The batch file will not proceed until they press a y or n.  I should also note that your curly braces are doing no good in your string comparison.  If the user enters: `Y E S` as input your script will fail. You need to enclose your string comparisons in double quotes.

Comment: Remove all the `exit` statements. Remove `echo off`. Then you all can just read it. You are telling it to hide everything from you.

Comment: I suspect that your people are probably selecting the file within windows explorer by using the arrow keys to go down to the file and then hitting the enter key twice.  This would bypass the `SET /P` command because the buffer sent the second {enter} key to the batch file as input.

Comment: @CatCat, the input is being output to the screen. It is the third line of code.  There are also multiple `PAUSE` commands to see the output before exiting the batch file.  The exit commands are needed so that the `:no` label is not executed when the answer is `yes`.

Comment: `Goto :eof` should be used. Removing `Exit` means the window stays open so you can read it.

Comment: @CatCat, `EXIT /B` does not close the window when the script is launched from a cmd prompt.  It acts just like `GOTO :EOF`. Double clicking a script with your mouse will close the window no matter what.

Comment: @Squashman I'm like your suggestion of the `CHOICE` command and researching how to use it.  Locking user to prompt until answering with provided choices only will help prevent user fat-fingering.  I'm also cleaning up the code as I edited some PING commands and replaced with SLEEP.  Updated the flow to be cleaner.  I'll research using log file output of user input as answered by @lit in second test.

Comment: @LordByron `SLEEP`???  That was from old versions of Windows. I would suggest using the `TIMEOUT` command instead. But some people will tell you to continue using `PING` because it takes up less CPU usage.  Another option is to use `PATHPING` because it provides a way to have millisecond delays. `pathping -q 1 -p 300 localhost >nul`.

Comment: @Squashman I just learned the hard way that `SLEEP` isn't valid command...so I went back to `PING`.  Currently trying to figure out why `CHOICE` isn't registering user input. Either `CHOICE /N /C:YN /M "Have checks been deposited and daily balance file SAVED and CLOSED? (Y/N)"` isn't working or `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO No` and `IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Yes` is being used wrong.

Comment: @LordByron, do not put that much code in a comment.  Update your question with any new additional information you would like to provide.  I think your problem is the order of the `IF` commands.  The help file for the `CHOICE` command clearly states to check them in descending order.

Comment: @LordByron You also have the errorlevels Reversed.  The choices are Y and N.  So errorlevel 1 is yes and errorlevel 2 is no. You should be able to see that from the answer posted below.

Comment: @LordByron, I am pretty sure you read the help file but I will post this as well. **NOTE: The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.**

Comment: @LordByron, you were given an answer below.  StackOverFlow is a question and answer site.  If someone answers your question you should be providing feedback on that.  You don't figure it out and then update your question with your answer.  If you want to answer your own question you can do that as well.  Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Lordbyron Additionally, you should not edit your answer into your question. Add it below, and accept it if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The code below omits some of the actual work in order to focus on flow control. I suspect the real problem will be determining where the LOGFILE will be and its name. This code will name it the same as the .bat file, but with ".log" as the extension.

```
@echo off
SET "LOGFILE=%TEMP%\%~n0.log"

CHOICE /M Have checks been deposited and daily balance file saved?
ECHO>>"%LOGFILE%" Choice at %DATE% %TIME% by %USERNAME% is %ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (GOTO No)

:Yes
rem ...
echo Daily Backup has completed!
pause
exit /b 0

:No
echo Please run DailyBackup once the deposit has been completed.
pause
exit /b 1
```

**UPDATE:**

At Squashman's suggestion, I have included the functional code. I have also used an IF/ELSE rather than GOTO. In addition, it accomplishes the file rename without a FOR loop.

```
@echo off
SET "LOGFILE=%TEMP%\%~n0.log"

CHOICE /M Have checks been deposited and daily balance file saved?

ECHO>>%LOGFILE% Choice at %DATE% %TIME% by %USERNAME% is %ERRORLEVEL%

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1  (
    for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "DailyBalance.xlsm" %%e-%%f-%%g-Deposit.xlsm
    echo File Rename Complete!
    pause
    move "C:\Deposit\*Deposit.xlsm" "C:\Deposit\Complete\"
    echo Renamed File Move Complete!
    pause
    copy "C:\Deposit\Reset\DailyBalance.xlsm" "C:\Deposit\"
    echo Daily Balance File Refreshed and ready for tomorrow!
    echo Daily Backup has completed!
    SET "EXITCODE=0"
) ELSE (
    echo Please run DailyBackup once the deposit has been completed.
    SET "EXITCODE=1"
)

pause
exit /b %EXITCODE%
```

Comment: Hi Lit, you might want to update your answer with all of their code.  They seem to be struggling implementing the choice commands into their existing code. See comments above.

Comment: I think the date format on their computer might be **DOW MM/DD/YYYY** which is why they were using the `FOR` command to get rid of the `DOW`.